# Random vs. Non-Random bullet examples

Tags: javascript, animation, game-physics, phaser-framework

I got stuck with the following (Phaser/Javascript);  There are 4 'bullets' with a timer of 18 seconds.  During that 18 seconds, each bullet flys from one side of the game screen (let's say 800 x 600) to the other, i.e. straight across, diagonally, etc.
Got into a debate over random (what this is) vs. non-random.  I think non-random would be better in this situation, becuase there is always something not quite right with the random method.

here is the complicated 'random' existing version (the bullet part anyway):
------------------------------------------------->

```
    var bullet = null;
    var flagBullet = false;
    var flagGameover = false;


    var bullet_type      =  [ 3,  1,  2,  4,];
    var init_posX_bullet =  [ 0,  0,  0,400,];
    var init_posY_bullet =  [ 0,600,300,  0,];
    var init_idxX_bullet =  [-1, -1, -1,  0,];
    var init_idxY_bullet =  [-1,  1,  0, -1,];
    var min_speedX_bullet = [ 5,  5,  5,  0,];
    var max_speedX_bullet = [10, 10, 10,  0,];
    var min_speedY_bullet = [ 5, -5,  0,  5,];
    var max_speedY_bullet = [10,-10,  0, 10,];


    var maxTime = 18; //in SECOND
    var timerEvent = null;

    var canHit = true;
```

//bullets

```
    bullet = game.add.sprite(-1000,0,"all_bullets");
    bullet.anchor.set(0.5);
    bullet.type = 1;
    bullet.minSpd = 0;
    bullet.maxSpd = 0;
    bullet.animations.add("b1",[3],1,false);
    bullet.animations.add("b2",[0],1,false);
    bullet.animations.add("b3",[1],1,false);
    bullet.animations.add("b4",[2],1,false);
    bullet.animations.play("b1");

    function initBullet(){

    canHit = true;
```

<---------------------------------------------------

But these are not your regular game bullets, they are objects; object1, object2, object3, object4 (each one different size/shape - different velocity too)  There is a central stationary object in the center of the screen. This is all 2-D.
Pretty 'plain'.
Can not find a good example of this online, there are various tweens, but almost all 'multiple' ones seem to be random.

---

What would something like this (non-random) look like in code?

start timer (18 seconds)

pause (adjustable)
Object1 flys across the screen (a miss - no collision possible)

pause (adjustable)
Object2 flys across the screen (possible collision)

pause (adjustable)
Object3 flys across the screen (a miss - no collision possible)

pause (adjustable)
Object4 flys across the screen (possible collision)

pause (adjustable)

### End Timer (end of game - if no collision)

Anyone else deal with the same or similar situation?

Comment: ??? What... The problem with non random is it is the same every time. So for non random you use the same random code and set the random seed to a constant. Digital devices are deterministic and without external input are incapable of randomness. For javascript you can not set the seed, it is set from the OS time, in that case use the same code as the random code replacing the `Math.random` function with array lookup `mySeq[sequenceIndex ++]` and you have your (apparent) non random code.

Comment: @Blindman67 - You lost me on most of that, I'm not a javascript expert - can you cite an example, just a short one will do.  See I was also looking at the possibility of just using a bunch of tweens in sequence (with pauses in between).  That may be messy, but it also might work.